# Enforcing Order of Excution in CloudSim

Tags: java

In cloudSim how can I enforce that cloudlet_2 should start after cloudlet_1 (Speaking of their execution time) ?

I try to do it some thing like this:

```
cloudlet_2.setExecStartTime(cloudlet_1.getFinishTime());
```

But this has no effect at run time, both of the cloudlets start at 0.0sec.

Is there any mechanism to enforce cloudlet_2 to not start execution (or even not submitted to the data-center) before cloudlet_1 finish executing ?

this can be by setting start time or by imposing some boolean condition on cloudlet_2, or other trick ... ???

The above requirement comes from the fact that I need some pipeline computation pattern of cloudlets that should execute one after the other (not at once.)

thanks.

Comment: Depending on your performance you could spin the second something like: `while(!cloudlet_1.done());` For better performance you could use a `conditional variable` and a `lock`.

Comment: what do you mean by : while(!cloudlet_1.done()); ?
that is what I want specifically. there is no such method "done()" in cloudSim.

Comment: I figured there wasn't a `done()` method I was just using that as an example. Is there any flag/way to tell when a `cloudSim` finishes?

Comment: There is a `getCloudletStatus()` method. Take a look at this it probably will tell you whether or not it finished. (Probably returns the `Cloudlet.SUCCESS` value when it finishes so it would be `while(cloudlet_1.getCloudletStatus() != Cloudlet.SUCCESS);` To be more robust you might want to check against the error statuses as well.

Comment: thank you very much, it is correct that condition like: if(cloudlet_1.getCloudletStatus() != Cloudlet.SUCCESS) allows you to check status of the cloudlet under consideration. But this condition can be checked either before submitting the cloudlets to a broker (which is useless) or after they are executed on data-center(to report their status to a user) 
My case is a bit different,after those cloudlets are mapped to a data-center, there should be a way that cloudlet "executer" look at property of the submitted cloudlets and execute them immediately or delay them for a while.
thank you any way!

Answer (score 0):

Which cloudlet gets executed when is totally depends on your scheduling policy. Here what you need is something like FCFS policy. Actually Cloudsim's default scheduling policy is FCFS.

But as per your requirement "cloudlet_2 should start after cloudlet_1",you need to change the vm/cloudlet scheduling policy. I think what you need is SpaceSharedPolicy for both vm/cloudlet scheduler.Butt not sure.

There are 4 cases for applying different scheduling policy, you can refer [Figure No 4 of this.](http://www.buyya.com/papers/CloudSim2010.pdf)

And about how to change these schedulers in code, you can refer [examples](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/examples/CloudSimExample1.java) which is already there in Cloudsim package.

For instance, if you want to change VM scheduler ,you can change parameter *[VmSchedulerTimeShared or VmSchedulerSpaceShared]* at line no 188 of above example and for changing cloudlet scheduler you can change parameter  *[CloudletSchedulerTimeShared() or  CloudletSchedulerSpaceShared() ]* at line no 104 of above example.